# Confusion about the precedence of ` * ` dereference operator & ` . ` dot or member access operator

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, operator-precedence

```
class Deep
{
private:
    int *data;

public:
    int getDataValue() { return *data; }

    // Constructor
    Deep(int d)
    {
        data = new int;
        *data = d;
    }

    // Deep Copy constructor
    Deep(const Deep &source)
        : Deep{*source.data}
    {
        cout << "Copy constructor is called - Deep" << endl;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Deep()
    {
        delete data;
        cout << "Destructor freeing data" << endl;
    }
};
```

why `*source.data` return an `int`?

Wasn't it supposed to be `*(source.data)`?

I have tried both lines `*source.data` and `*(source.data)` and the result is same.

Also, why `*(source).data` return the same result of `*source.data`,
although `()` has higher precedence

Comment: *"Wasn't it supposed to be `*(source.data)?`"* Yes, it's equivalent to that. *"`*(source).data` which it is an error"* That's a valid piece of code, and it's also equivalent to the above. Both are equivalent to `*((source).data)`.

Comment: ". dot operator has higher precedence than *", exactly. So why are you surprised when the `.` is evaluated first?

Comment: Perhaps the error was on `(*source).data`?

Comment: It appears that you have your own ideas about how evaluating expressions work, and that your question is based on the assumption that others agree with you. However, (likely) no one else has a clue as to what that is. For example, `*(source).data` evaluates the same as `*source.data` in part because `()` has higher precedence. Yet you see some sort of contradiction here. Why? Could you add a few sentences, or even paragraphs explaining how you see the evaluation of these expressions? Rule of thumb: assume those answering will agree with the compiler, so it's on you to explain your perspective.

Answer (score 2):

The data member `data` has the pointer type `int *`.

So the postfix expression `source.data` yields the pointer. Dereferencing the pointer expression `*source.data` you get an integer.

Postfix operators have higher precedence than unary operators.

That is the expression `*source.data` is evaluated like `*( source.data )`.

Also this expression `*(source).data` is the same as this expression `*(source.data)` and in turn is the same as this expression `*source.data`. I think you are mistaken saying that the compiler issues an error for this expression `*(source).data`.

From the C++17 Standard (8.2.5 Class member access)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by a dot . or an arrow ->, optionally
> followed by the keyword template (17.2), and then followed by an
> id-expression, is a postfix expression. The postfix expression before
> the dot or arrow is evaluated;67 the result of that evaluation,
> together with the id-expression, determines the result of the entire
> postfix expression.

Comment: sorry, I don't quite understand the last part, I know that `()` has higher precedence so why does it return the same result? I am a beginner so excuse me for the confusion

Comment: @night_ZAK - Where is the confusion? `(source)` is evaluated first, and gives you `source`. As does `(((((source)))))`.

Comment: @BoP but is it not `*(source)` first? and if not why?

Comment: @night_ZAK In his expression  ( source) is a promary expression  to which the member acessss operator is applied.  And only after that the unary operator * is applied . That is the postfix operator has a higher precedence than the unary operator *.

Comment: @night_ZAK *"but is it not `*(source)` first?"* -- Again, these are details you should put in the question so that answer can address your misunderstandings without this back-and-forth. The precedence of parentheses means that what is **inside** the parentheses is evaluated first. You are asking about something **outside** the parentheses, so the precedence of parentheses is not applicable.